# How do I read the IP address from a failed logon event in the event viewer using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to read the data from an Audit Failure event generated by a failed logon attempt. I can get the events I need, but I can't figure out how to actually get the IP address from the event.

To clarify, I want see the event generated by a failed windows  logon attempt from a user. Looks like this in XML view in event log

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
        <EventID>4625</EventID> 
        ... 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        ...
        <Data Name="IpAddress">xxx.xxx.171.130</Data> 
        <Data Name="IpPort">50717</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Can you see the IP address when you examine the event in the Event Viewer's UI?

Comment: How does the logon work?

Comment: Yes the IP address is right there. It's just a logon attempt via RDC.

Comment: If you have the `EventLogEntry`s, the address should be a member of the `ReplacementStrings` array property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [ordag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516656/ordag) posted in the above question comment thread, the information I wanted was in the ReplacementStrings array.

Quote:

> If you have the EventLogEntrys, the address should be a member of the
>   ReplacementStrings array property.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET use:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: You can access the Windows Event Log as ASP server variables?

Comment: Probably not, I just answered the questions asked with what i thought was corcect. At that time i could as well have been asp.net. Now it doesn't look like ASP.NET ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you hid the actual ip address when posting by replacing the first two octets then just use xml or regex to read it in, but if it's exactly as you posted:

```
<Data Name="IpAddress">xxx.xxx.171.130</Data>
```

Then no, you can't from the event log, though if you're lucky and are in a small network with only one segment then you could figure it out.

For example if you're in a small network, you know there's only one segment you can incorporate that into your program's logic, like in your example `...171.130`, if you know your network has an address in range **192.168.171.1-192.168.171.254** then you can be 100% certain that it came from **192.168.17.130**, on the other hand if you know there is some other network in the range of **172.21.171.1-172.21.171.254** then you won't know, unless you know for sure, that the other segments cannot talk to your computer, you can usually ask your network people to find this out.

See this for a reference for ip and subnet calculations http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=C